# string macro replacement

Tags: c#, regex, string, replace

I have a Visual Studio 2008 C# .NET 3.5 application where I need to parse a macro.

Given a serial serial number that is N digits long, and a macro like `%SERIALNUMBER3%`, I would like this parse method to return only the first 3 digits of the serial number.

```
string serialnumber = "123456789";
string macro = "%SERIALNUMBER3%";
string parsed = SomeParseMethod(serialnumber, macro);

parsed = "123"
```

Given `%SERIALNUMBER7%, return the first 7 digits, etc..

I can do this using `String.IndexOf` and some complexity, but I wondered if there was a simple method. Maybe using a `Regex` replace.

What's the simplest method of doing this?

Comment: What is this magical macro thing you are talking about?

Comment: @leppie - He seems to mean a string delimited in both sides by `%`. That's probably a token to be replaced.

Comment: If I understand correctly, a relatively simple regex.replace will do the trick.

Comment: How sophisticated does SomeParseMethod() need to be. For instance, is SERIALNUMBER the only macro you anticipate. If you have others, what sort of manipulation do you expect them to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var str = "%SERIALNUMBER3%";
var reg = new Regex(@"%(\w+)(\d+)%");
var match = reg.Match( str );
if( match.Success )
{
    string token = match.Groups[1].Value;
    int numDigits = int.Parse( match.Groups[2].Value );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Regex` class. Your expression will be something like:

```
@"%(\w)+(\d)%"
```

Your first capture group is the ID (in this case, "SERIALNUMBER"), and your second capture group is the number of digits (in this case, "3").

Answer (score 0):

Very quick and dirty example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string serialnumber = "123456789";
            string macro = "%SERIALNUMBER3%";

            var match = Regex.Match(macro, @"\d+");

            string parsed = serialnumber.Substring(0, int.Parse(match.ToString()));
        }
```